# Определение координат элемента на странице

Tags: javascript, css, css3

**1**.Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли из DOM определить координаты элемента(по имени класса или его id), к примеру относительно всего документа ?

То есть не используя какие либо функции JS, чисто ручками, то есть я хотел бы понять принцип, как самому достать данные, а точнее наверное рассчитать эти данные исходя из имеющейся информации об элементе в DOM.

**2**.И что в рамках HTML - вообще такое координаты ? В чем они измерятся ? В пикселях ?

Comment: Что значит "не используя какие-либо функции JS, а чисто ручками"?

Comment: @Neverm1ndo, у меня есть доступ ко всему DOM из С/C++ - кода. Имелось ввиду, что парсить DOM вручную с помощью только  С/C++ функций.

Comment: т.е `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` вызвать не получится, так?

Comment: @Neverm1ndo, есть возможности вызывать js из с++ кода, но это очень не удобно(для меня) и самое главное - я не знаю JS.

Comment: Лучше вызывайте JS, так будет проще. А как посчитать координаты относительно всего документа вам расписал @EzioMercer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно прчитать [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) и https://learn.javascript.ru/coordinates

Но он даст координаты не относительно всего документа, а ближайшего, кто в себе содержит этот элемент. Это значит, что если у элемента например положение `absolute`, то он даст координаты относительно первого `relative`, если таковых нет, то даст относительно всего документа

На счёт того как посчитать, то первое что приходит в голову - это доставать родителя пока не дойдешь до `body` и попутно считать координаты относительно нынешного элемента. Скорее есть более продуманные алгоритмы

А координаты, насколько я знаю - это пиксели

Answer (score 1):

Ещё координаты относительно окна можно получить так:

```
let x = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("left"));
let y = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("top"));
```

Теперь об определении координат элемента по **id** и **class**. Допустим, есть такой элемент:

```
<div id=mydiv class=myclass>див</div>
```

Определить по id можно любым из этих вариантов:

```
let x = parseInt(getComputedStyle(mydiv).left);
```

или

```
let x = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(mydiv).getPropertyValue('left'));
```

или

```
let x = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('[id=mydiv]')).left);
```

Определить по классу можно любым из этих вариантов:

```
let x = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.myclass')).left);
```

или

```
let x = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('[class=myclass]')).left);
```

или

```
let x = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0]).left);
```

Теперь о том, какова существует разница в работе **getComputedStyle()** и **getBoundingClientRect()**.

Для того, чтобы работало первое, нужно, чтобы в стилях было прописано соответствующее свойство CSS, (top или left) либо **position: absolute** или **relative** в противном случае выдаст **NaN**. Функция возвращает координаты в пикселях даже если их прописать в процентах. И ещё, если прописаны top или left, но не указано position, то функция возвращает то, что прописано, но на самом деле элемент на странице может находиться в другом месте.

**getBoundingClientRect()** возвращает координаты всегда в пикселях, при чём, с многими знаками после запятой. И это значение соответствует реальной позиции элемента на странице независимо от того, что прописано в стилях.

Comment: Спасибо, а куда мне имя класса или имя id элемента - указать ?

Comment: @Я дополнил ответ

Comment: @Опан если уж делаете сниппет, то тогда хотя делайте его воспроизводимым, а если же хотите включить несколько вариантов, делайте просто используя синтаксис Markdown для выделения кода или же используйте несколько сниппетов.

Comment: Странно, применяю getBoundingClientRect(): elem = document.getElementById("my_ID");rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect(); alert(rect.x + \":\" + rect.y). Но координаты выдаются совершенно не верные.

Comment: Проверю коордианты обьекта по клике на его верхний угол: "window.addEventListener('click', function(event){alert(event.pageX + \":\" + (event.pageY))}, false)"  - вот эти коордианты Верные и совершенно отличаются от тех, что возвращает getBoundingClientRect.

Comment: Ой sorry, я напутал - все работает нормально.